# What's the equivalent of new/delete of C++ in C?

Tags: c++, c, new-operator, delete-operator

What's the equivalent of new/delete of C++ in C?

Or it's the same in C/C++?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's no `new`/`delete` expression in C.

The closest equivalent are the [`malloc` and `free` functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc), if you ignore the constructors/destructors and type safety.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int* p = malloc(sizeof(*p));   // int* p = new int;
...
free(p);                       // delete p;

int* a = malloc(12*sizeof(*a));  // int* a = new int[12];
...
free(a);                         // delete[] a;
```

Comment: *@KennyTM:* Does `sizeof(*p)` actually dereference `p`, or is it fully equivalent to writing `sizeof(int)`? It seems that in the former case, this expression would potentially cause a segmentation fault (because `p` is not yet assigned at this point). In the latter case, I would probably still prefer writing `sizeof(int)` because there's less potential for misunderstanding what this statement does.

Comment: @stakx: The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time. There's no dereferencing. `sizeof(*p)` is preferred to `sizeof(int)` because if you change the type of `p` to `double` the compiler cannot warn you of size mismatch.

Comment: @stakx The `sizeof` operator is a mapping from **type** to `size_t`. The **value** of its operand is not interesting at all. For example, in `sizeof(1 + 2)`, there is absolutely no need to compute the result `3`. The `sizeof` operator simply sees an expression of type `int + int` and infers that the result is also an `int`. Then it maps `int` to 4 (or 2 or 8, depending on the platform). It's the same thing with `sizeof(*p)`. The type system knows that, on the type level, dereferencing an `int*` yields an `int`. `sizeof` is not interested in the value of `*p` at all, only the type matters.

Comment: @stakx For exactly the same reason, `sizeof(1/0)` does NOT crash horribly with an arithmetic exception, but instead yields `sizeof(int)`, because `1` is of type `int`, `0` is of type `int`, and the division of two `int`s also yields an `int` on the type level. The division is never executed, neither at compile time nor at runtime!

Comment: Thanks to both of you for replying. I thought I'd ask because I haven't seen this usage of `sizeof` before. Good thing to know, though!

Comment: @KennyTM Nice answer. Would like to ask: why is the following considered a more proper way when using sizeof:       malloc(sizeof (*p)); note the single space between sizeof and (*p)? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig: `sizeof (*p)` and `sizeof(*p)` are just equivalent. You could also omit the parenthesis for expressions `sizeof *p`.

Answer (score 11):

Note that constructors might throw exceptions in C++. The equivalent of `player* p = new player();` would be something like this in C.

```
struct player *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
if (!p) handle_out_of_memory();
int err = construct_player(p);
if (err)
{
    free(p);
    handle_constructor_error();
}
```

The equivalent of `delete p` is simpler, because destructors should never "throw".

```
destruct(p);
free(p);
```

Comment: What would `construct_player` look like?

Answer (score 8):

Use of `new` and `delete` in C++ combines two responsibility - allocating/releasing dynamic memory, and initialising/releasing an object.

As all the other answers say, the most common way to allocate and release dynamic memory is calling `malloc` and `free`. You also can use OS-specific functions to get a large chunk of memory and allocate your objects in that, but that is rarer - only if you have fairly specific requirements that malloc does not satisfy.

In C, most APIs will provide a pair of functions which fulfil the other roles of `new` and `delete`.

For example, the file api uses a pair of open and close functions:

```
// C++
fstream* fp = new fstream("c:\\test.txt", "r");
delete fp;

// C
FILE *fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "r"); 
fclose(fp);
```

It may be that `fopen` uses `malloc` to allocate the storage for the `FILE` struct, or it may statically allocate a table for the maximum number of file pointers on process start. The point is, the API doesn't require the client to use `malloc` and `free`.

Other APIs provide functions which just perform the initialisation and releasing part of the contract - equivalent to the constructor and destructor, which allows the client code to use either automatic , static or dynamic storage. One example is the pthreads API:

```
pthread_t thread;

pthread_create( &thread, NULL, thread_function, (void*) param);
```

This allows the client more flexibility, but increases the coupling between the library and the client - the client needs to know the size of the `pthread_t` type, whereas if the library handles both allocation and initialisation the client does not need to know the size of the type, so the implementation can vary without changing the client at all. Neither introduces as much coupling between the client and the implementation as C++ does. (It's often better to think of C++ as a template metaprogramming language with vtables than an OO language)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what specific requirements malloc does not satisfy?

Comment: @Pacerier `malloc` allocates memory. `operator new` (usually) allocates memory *and* initialises the memory to contain values supplied by the constructor of the class of object specified. ( there is a variable of `operator new` called 'placement new' which does not allocate memory, so you can use malloc for the first part, and new for the second if you so wish)

Answer (score 3):

Not directly an exact replica but compatible equivalents are malloc and free.

```
<data-type>* variable = (<data-type> *) malloc(memory-size);
free(variable);
```

No constructors/destructors - C anyway doesn't have them :)

To get the memory-size, you can use `sizeof` operator.

If you want to work with multidimensional arrays, you will need to use it multiple times (like new):

```
int** ptr_to_ptr = (int **) malloc(12 * sizeof(int *)); //assuming an array with length 12.
ptr[0] = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));   //1st element is an array of 10 items
ptr[1] = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));    //2nd element an array of 5 elements etc
```

Comment: In C you don't need to cast from void* to other pointers. Its just
int* p = malloc( sizeof(int) * cElements);

Comment: Chris: Are you sure? I haven't worked with C for quite some time now, but IIRC, I had to do it because the return type of malloc is void *.

Comment: In c `void*` automatically converts to other pointer types. Casting the return of malloc can cause errors if you haven't included `stdlib.h`, as the parameters will have been assumed to be `int`.

Comment: Explicitly casting from `void*` to other pointer types is necessary in C++ but not in C.

Comment: @Scott, @Jamesdlin: Thanks. It seems I've become rusty in C ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use malloc / free functions.

Answer (score 1):

Late, but I really like this syntax, although I'm not sure if it fits ways of C

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define new(type, length) malloc(sizeof(type)*(length))
#define delete(x) free(x)
int main()
{
    int *test = new(int, 30);
    delete(test);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I like it... At least you should enclose `length` in brackets.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to achieve it with macros so I've done what I could

Comment: You should always put brackets around macro parameters. See my edit. You might think about the result of `new(int,4+5)` without the brackets around `length`